# Xcode Devices and Simulators windows stays blank

Tags: xcode

I run Xcode 15.0.1 and my Devices and Simulators windows started to stay blank after a certain day. Rebooting the Mac, restarting Xcode did not help. Problem persists with Xcode 15.1 Beta 2.
Anyone had the same problem and knows a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to get the window's contents to reappear after resizing the window.  I had also unsuccessfully tried all of the same stuff you did before finding this question.  This seems to be a simple cosmetic bug in Xcode.

Comment: Thank you. Been trying to fix this for the past few days.